# Mysqli wont allow table's to show when called on

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

As of recently ive been learning php and at that conjuntion in between where i have to now use Mysql in order to keep my bigger info table ogranized, well i wrote this code in order to show the tables (or so i think i did it right). im completely stumped because i can not see any of the displaying tables that i am calling on and the more ive tried the less i works so i was wondering if anyone can see a loop hole in my code or maybe im doing something wrong? or maybe everything ive done is wrong...?

`

```
    $dbhost = "localhost";
    $dbuser = "juliegri_AAlassa";
    $dbpass = "********"; // to not show real password
    $dbname =  "juliegri_AAlassaly";
    $connection = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

    if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        die("Database connection failed: " .
            mysqli_connect_error() . 
             " (" . mysqli_connect_errno () . ")"
             );

    }
?>


<?php

    $query = "SELECT * ";
    $query .= "FROM subjects ";
    $query .= "WHERE visible = 1 ";
    $query .= "ORDER BY position ASC";

    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    if (!$result) {
        die("Database query failed");
    }


?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>databases</title>
</head>
<body>
 <ul>
    <?php
        while($subject = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            ?>
            <li><?php echo $subject["menu_name"] . "(" . $subject["id"] . ")"; ?></li>

        <?php
            }
        ?>
</ul>
    <?php
     mysqli_free_result($result);
    ?>

 </body>
</html>
<?php
 mysqli_close($connection);
?>`
```

Comment: What is the result of your current page?

Comment: @PatrickReck Blank completely blank

Answer (score 0):

Have you forgotten the opening PHP tag at the beginning of your page?

```
<?php

$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "juliegri_AAlassa";
$dbpass = "********"; // to not show real password
$dbname =  "juliegri_AAlassaly";
$connection = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    die("Database connection failed: " .
        mysqli_connect_error() . 
         " (" . mysqli_connect_errno () . ")"
         );

}

$query = "SELECT * ";
$query .= "FROM subjects ";
$query .= "WHERE visible = 1 ";
$query .= "ORDER BY position ASC";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
if (!$result) {
    die("Database query failed");
}

?>
```

Comment: I'm not too sure if i have im still pretty amateur at this.

Answer (score 0):

Two things i think could be wrong.

[Here is a correct implementation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.statements.php) to compare. It could be the first PHP opening tag, i also added the default port to the connect statement, and added some try catches with error messages, these can tell if the connect or query is not working.

```
<?php

$dbhost =  "localhost";
$dbuser =  "juliegri_AAlassa";
$dbpass =  "********"; // to not show real password
$dbname =  "juliegri_AAlassaly";

//original connect statement with a port added in
try {
     $connection = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname , 3306);
} catch(Exception $e) { echo $e->getMessage(); }


if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}


//Query looks fine, easier to trouble shoot when its one line, first get it working then break it up
$query = "SELECT * FROM subjects WHERE visible = 1 ORDER BY position ASC";

// This will try to fetch the result and give an error if it can't.
try {  $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
} catch(Exception $e) { echo $e->getMessage(); }

if (!$result) { die("Database query failed"); }

?>
```

Comment: i tried this and now i get db query failed, im following Lynda.com's tuts and it said everything was okay but no result but when i use your snipet it tell me i have an error, theres still only one problem i cant see where i may be wrong... here would be the link to the ulpoaded server [link](http://juliegrimes.com/aalassaly/sandbox/14/DBselect11.php)

Comment: With a little mishap which ive now fixed is still get that darned blank screen...

Comment: @Coolbeans do you have error_reports enabled? http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Answer (score 0):

Is it alright if I alter some of your codes?

See this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>databases</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php

/* ESTABLISH CONNECTION */

$connection=mysqli_connect("localhost","juliegri_AAlassa","YourPassword","juliegri_Aalassaly");

if(mysqli_connect_errno()){

echo "Error".mysqli_connect_error();
}

/* START QUERY */

$result=mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM subjects WHERE visible='1' ORDER BY position ASC");

?>

<ul>
<?php

/* DO THE WHILE LOOP */

while($subject = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
?>
<li><?php echo $subject['menu_name'] . "(" . $subject['id'] . ")"; ?></li>

<?php
} /* END OF WHILE LOOP */
?>

</ul>
</body>
</html>
```